# how to use timeouts with read() on a socket in c++ on Unix

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, timeout

I want to use read() with ioctl(), but want to control how much time read should wait, by using a timeout.
Any idea on how to do this?

so far what i know is:

```
//CLIENT.cpp
struct timeval tv={1,0};
setsockopt( mysocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &tv, sizeof(tv));
connect(mysocket, &sock_dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
len = read(mysocket, buffer, 10);
```

I tried using a 5 sec delay on server, but it did not timeout...

Comment: You could try setting `O_NONBLOCK` with [fcntl(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) and then using [select(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) to find out when the socket is ready to read from (select allows you to specify a timeout).

Comment: Agreed.  BTW, if you care how long the `read` takes, you should probably care how long `connect` takes too (it can be a while, if it times out). You can make the socket nonblocking before calling `connect`, and handle both via `select` or `poll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ioctl()` won't do what you want. To use a timeout on reads you need to use `poll()` or the older interface `select()` (I'd use `poll()`). The timeout set with `SO_RCVTIMEO` may get reset every time new data is received. So, for your example it may wait for up to 10 seconds. `poll()` returns after the specified timeout telling you whether there is any data. Once that is the case you can just read whatever is there using non-blocking `read()`.

Comment: i am using ioctl to chk how many bytes can be read, if nothing is ready yet, loop again, but read being a blocking call, use timeout to proceed ahead. The purpose is to replace the SELECT calls.

Comment: Well, setting `SO_RCTTIMEO` to a value of `timeout / size` (where `timeout` is in seconds and `size` is in bytes) should have an effect somewhat similar to this. Howeve, this flag seems to be not too portable and I would still use `poll()` (or `select()` if `poll()` somehow isn't available). Why would you want to remove these calls? They deal nicely with timeouts.

Comment: there are too many select calls using the same timeout value, causing the undefined behaviour, this way i want to implement retries, and manage timeouts......

Comment: Did you consider dealing with multiple file descriptors at once? If you have many simultaneous `select()`s active and this is causing problem I would assume that using `SO_RCVTIMEO` is actually more likely to cause problems then remove some...

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want by setting up an alarm to interrupt the system call.  You need some basic setup somewhere in main or early in your program init process:

```
#include <signal.h>

sig_atomic_t alarm_counter;

void alarm_handler(int signal) {
    alarm_counter++;
}

void setup_alarm_handler() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sa.flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, 0) < 0)
        die("Can't establish signal handler");
}
// call setup_alarm_handler in main
```

Then, you can use it like:

```
alarm(10); // set a 10 second timeout
(len = connect(mysocket, &sock_dest, sizeof(struct sockaddr))) < 0 ||
(len = read(mysocket, buffer, 10));
alarm(0); // cancel alarm if it hasn't happened yet
if (len == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    // timed out before any data read
else if (len == -1)
    // other error
```

This way you can have a timeout for a sequence of calls (this will timeout if either the connect or the read takes too long individually or in total), rather than having to figure out how long each call took, so you know how long to wait for each subsequent call.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's blocking on the read, or is it perhaps blocking on the connect()? I don't believe that the SO_RCVTIMEO (and SO_SNDTIMEO) options affect the connect() behavior.

In general, I like to use non-blocking sockets (fcntl with O_NONBLOCK), and then catch the EWOULDBLOCK errno and do a select() with the socket in the read set and the desired timeout.